# Dynamically link libc in a static binary

Tags: gcc, static-linking, dynamic-linking, libc

I'm trying to compile a static binary, however a small part of the binary calls `getaddrinfo`. What I would like is to be able to statically link *everything* for the binary *except* for `libc`. Currently what I am doing is:

```
gcc -static index.c
```

I'm looking for something like:

```
gcc -static -dynamic-libc index.c
```

But I can't find anything that would let me do that.

Comment: `gcc foo.o bar.o -o prog -Wl,-Bstatic -lmylib -lotherlib -Wl,-Bdynamic -lc`